# Eigenvalue Slowdown in Sparse Matrices

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

Is there conditions (besides just sparsity) regarding the structure or contents of a matrix that can lead to significant slowdown in eigenvalue calculations? Such as in eig or eigs in Matlab.

I'm trying to run an algorithm whose main bottlenecks in speed are several eigenvalue calculation on large, sparse matrices. When I run the algorithm on the example matrices given by the algorithm (a 13309x13309 matrix), the runtime is fast as expected (for example, eigs runs in 0.014287 secs).

I attempt the same eigenvalue tests on my own smaller matrix, a 3087x3087 matrix. Yet the runtime is significantly longer (0.79211 secs for eigs, similar runtime increases for other eigenvalue calculations like eig). Although the matrix is significantly less sparse (0.11% non-zero entries instead of 0.027% non-zero entries originally), it is still significantly sparse, so I'm not sure if the issue is in the closeness of eigenvalues or some similar measure.

Comment: I suspect its the condition number, not sparsity, the main factor in speed. Sparse matrices just often have a worse condition number.

Comment: Different structures would cause different algorithms to be used to compute eigenvalues. The original matrix might be a triangular matrix, or a diagonal matrix (trivial solution!) or a band-diagonal matrix, all of which would be cheaper to get eigenvalues from than a random matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Computing eigenvalues can be more or less complex depending on the structure of the matrix, not just the number of zeros, but also where they are. MATLAB can choose different algorithms depending on the structure, but even with a fixed algorithm, some structures just give a lot less work than others. The obvious example is the diagonal matrix, where the eigenvalues are directly the diagonal elements, no computation is needed at all.

Here's an example with full matrices (similar results expected for `sparse` matrices):

```matlab
A = randn(1000);
tic
eig(A);
toc

A = tril(A);
tic
eig(A);
toc

A = toeplitz([5, 6, 2, zeros(1, 997)]);
tic
eig(A);
toc

A = diag(randn(1, 1000));
tic
eig(A);
toc
```

output:

```
Elapsed time is 0.682568 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039816 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.133101 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002881 seconds.
```

[Note that `tic`/`toc` is a bad way to measure short times like these, we should really be using `timeit` here.]

Note that the Toeplitz matrix has only 4994 non-zero elements, yet takes much longer to compute than the lower triangular matrix, which has half a million non-zero elements.